# cygwin ssh -- config

Tags: windows, hadoop, ssh, cygwin, system

I am using windows system and install cygwin64. I want to set ssh/sshd ready for future hadoop installation.
1. I installed openssh and openssl when installing cygwin;
2. I excute ssh-host-config -y command;
3. I set system variables path, classpath and java_home;
4. I start Cygwin sshd.

```
abc@WL000 ~
$ ssh -version
Bad escape character 'rsion'.
abc@WL000 ~
$ ssh -help
ssh: unknown option -- h
usage: ssh [-1246AaCfgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYy] [-b bind_address] [-c cipher_spec]
       [-D [bind_address:]port] [-E log_file] [-e escape_char]
       [-F configfile] [-I pkcs11] [-i identity_file]
       [-L [bind_address:]port:host:hostport] [-l login_name] [-m mac_spec]
       [-O ctl_cmd] [-o option] [-p port]
       [-Q cipher | cipher-auth | mac | kex | key]
       [-R [bind_address:]port:host:hostport] [-S ctl_path] [-W host:port]
       [-w local_tun[:remote_tun]] [user@]hostname [command]

abc@WL000 ~
$ sshd -version
sshd: unknown option -- v
OpenSSH_6.7p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1k 8 Jan 2015
usage: sshd [-46DdeiqTt] [-b bits] [-C connection_spec] [-c host_cert_file]
        [-E log_file] [-f config_file] [-g login_grace_time]
        [-h host_key_file] [-k key_gen_time] [-o option] [-p port]
        [-u len]
```

does it mean I set ssh in correct way? Thx!

Answer (score 0):

You installed it correctly, but you're using it incorrectly.

1. Long switches usually start with `--` (double dash) instead of `-`. Using `-help` usually is the same as using `-h -e -l -p`; what you want is `--help` or `-h` in 90% cases. That is why you get "invalid character 'rsion'": `e` in `-version` is interpreted as `-e`, and `-e` takes "escape char" as its argument. `rsion` obviously isn't valid escape character.
2. Neither SSH or SSHD support long switches. It means there is no `--help` or `--anything` for that matter, all config options these programs support are single character (i.e. `-D`, `-b` etc).
3. In fact, `ssh` and `sshd` offer no special help by means of CLI switches such as `-h` at all.
4. It doesn't mean they're not documented:

   1. Just run `ssh` to see short option list.
   2. Run `man ssh` to see comprehensive information about its usage.

I recommend getting familiar with `man`, as it is a standard tool for documenting programs on Linux and Cygwin. For example, you can see `ls` documentation by running `man ls`.